# How do I create an external .exe file using Java

Tags: java

I am storing all of the bytes of an external .exe file, and then re-writing them to another .exe file that I am currently creating with FileOutputStream/BufferedOutputStream.

The bytes are written fine, and the second program is created in the location of my choice, but when I come to run the file, it says it's not a valid .exe file or not a valid 32/64bit application.

I'm guessing because it's not packed and generated properly.

How would I make it so it's an executable file and works the same as the first one?

p.s I can't use any copying of the file, because eventually I'm going to be encrypting the bytes and writing them to the file, but I still want it to be usable.

Comment: I'm making a crypter, I need to know how to do this so if you know please share.

Comment: What happens when you run from cmd prompt "fc old.exe new.exe".  Does your new .exe really have exactly the same bytes?

Comment: From what I can see yes, all the bytes are exactly the same, file size is the same. They aren't messed wtih at all, grabbed from original and written to new but I can't execute the new one.

Comment: That sounds a bit doubtfull. What is the purpose of that crypter? You dont want to  use that for illigal actions?

Comment: If the bytes are identical, then the file will run.  Perhaps you could provide detail explaining how you know the files are identical?

Answer (score 0):

If all the bytes are identical it will run. If the original file runs and the copy doesn't then some of the bytes have to be different. It has nothing to do with packing.
Maybe you are using a byte variable to store the read data. Don't do that. Just use int. If you don't use byte variables correctly you can run into problems due to automatic sign extension.

This works fine for me

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("a.exe"));
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("b.exe"));
        int data = in.read();
        while(data >= 0) {
            out.write(data);
            data = in.read();
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```